# Is there a way to put a copy rotation constraint with an influence higher than 1?

Tags: constraints

I'm making a little animation with some gears. I want that if I rotate the first gear, all the gears rotate with the gain given by the gears.

For doing that I've choose the copy rotation constraint. But in my case, sometime a gear turn one time and the second turn tiwce. With the copy roation I can only put an influence between 0 and 1.

So my question is : Is there a way to put a copy rotation constraint with an influence higher than 1? Or is there an other solution to do what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.0 is the maximum influence for any given constraint, so setting it beyond 1.0 is impossible.

Using the **Transformation** constraint, you could easily map any kind of simple transformation from one object to the other. In the following example, the object being constrained will rotate twice the amount of `Cube_target`'s rotation in the Y axis.

[image: 1a]

Checking **Extrapolation** will extend the transformation beyond stated range of values.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. But now I've an other problem. With the copy rotation and the transformation constraint, when the target object go from 179° to 180° or 539° to 540°, the objects with the constraint do a 'higher step' of rotation. Is it a bug or I'm doing somthing wrong?

Comment: @lucblender: I can't picture, let alone reproduce your problem. I redo this answer, and found nothing wrong at the angles your mentioned ([file at PasteAll](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25466)). A sample file would be helpful.

Comment: The bug appear when the ratio between the source and target object isn't somthing like 0.5, 1, 1.5 Here is a link to my blender file:https://www.dropbox.com/s/246ciar9hae8vda/engrenage%20V2.0.blend

Comment: OK, that looks like a bug on the extrapolation. Both Transformation and Copy Rotation are screwed there. An alternative solution is to drive the rotation directly ([File at PasteAll](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25467)). It's a bit more involving, but seems more stable.

Comment: Oooh driver that's a bit new to me. I'll try this thank you :)

Comment: I've found how to do it properly with driver. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use F-Curve Drivers.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMoBFzXFAUM

Use a scripted expression on the OWNER object's driver with the Target object set. By animating the TARGET object, the OWNER responds accordingly to the driver.

Eg: Two Cubes, CubeA and CubeB:

1. Add SINGLE DRIVER to CubeB's x rotation transform box.
2. Go to Graph window.
3. Change from F-Curveto Drivers.
4. Select it's X Rotation in the list on left side.
5. Scroll down in the right side panel to find Drivers.
6. Set Ob to CubeA Change Type to X Rotation (since we added single drive to x rotation).
7. In the field under Script Expression:
   Delete 0.00 and write var * 2 (var is the name of variable box we
   changed the ob/type in).

Now rotate on CubeA's x axis. CubeB rotates on the x axis at twice the speed.

Using this method, you will never have that 179-180 problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to simply stack copy rotation constraints, with offset enabled.

[image]

They'll add together.  Unpleasant if you wanted a 50:1 ratio, but easier than drivers or transformation constraints if you only need a 2:1 ratio.